# Highcharts - stacked columns by category

Tags: javascript, highcharts, multiple-columns, stacked-chart

I have this data:

```
Array
(
    [firefox 3.0] => 2
    [chrome 24.0] => 1
    [ie 9.0] => 2
    [ie 10.0] => 1
)
```

**Question:** How to add series to achieve wanted chart?

**My try:**

**JsFiddle:** [http://jsfiddle.net/fVrbQ](http://jsfiddle.net/fVrbQ/)

I want to have stacked chart like this:

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set x for columns: http://jsfiddle.net/fVrbQ/1/

```
 series: [{
            name: 'firefox 3.0',
            data: [[0,2]],
            stack:0
        }, {
            name: 'chrome 24.0',
            data: [[1,1]],
            stack:1
        }, {
            name: 'ie 9.0',
            data: [[2,2]],
            stack:2
        }, {
            name: 'ie 10.0',
            data: [[2,1]],
            stack:2
        }]
```